# DateTime selector format in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to change ASP.NET datetime from US to GB format.

I have an HTML page with:

```
<input asp-for="BirthDay" />
```

and its corresponding PageModel with:

```
public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
```

I get a date selector with the US date format:

```
Month/Day/Year
```

Instead I want to use the UK date format:

```
Day/Month/Year
```

I tried playing around with `CultureInfo` and some attributes to no avail. Any ideas?

Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

[image: want to change from US to GB format]

Comment: looks like Chrome's control there.  Note that different browsers will have different controls for this.  Seems like Chrome should pick a format based on your computer's region.

Comment: I did find this fiddle that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/g7mvaosL/

Comment: I tried several browsers. I also changed my computer's System locale to English (United Kingdom).

Comment: @pcalkins It had nothing to do with System locale but changing my computer's Date and Time format (Short date, the one that shows at the bottom-right corner on windows) also changed the browser's date selector format. If you post it, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `asp-format`?
For example something like that:

```
<input asp-for="BirthDay" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" />
```

Comment: I just tried that but it still gives me the old selector with month/day/year